# Storing Client Data for next page?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, web

I have a little project for authentication and I need to store an encryption key on website B which I get from the server on website A, but the server from website B should not be able to read it.
Is this possible without a browser extension? How would something like this be implemented?

I guess the broader question is: How do I store data from website A on website B without sending the data to server B?

If this is not enough: Before I get to website A in the first place I will be redirected from website B anyway.
I could do the following in this setting:

- create a temporary public/private key pair,
- store the private key in sessionStorage on website B,
- send the public key to server A on the redirect from website B
- use the public key to encrypt the userKey
- send the encrypted userKey to server B on the redirect from website A to website B
- deliver the encrypted Data to the client on website B
- decrypt it on the client with the key from sessionStorage

It feels like there should be a more simple solution though ..
Note: I trust the javascript code from website B but not the code on server B (as this will not be open to the public).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first things first, your last sentence is self-contradictory. If you don't trust the server for site B, you can't and mustn't trust any content from B, including scripts. If B is malicious or compromised, when you visit B you will get either an altered script that does something malicious, or just get an extra script that tacks malicious behavior onto the normal operations. For example, the malicious code could trivially retrieve the secret after you decrypt it, or just retrieve the secret and its decryption key directly.

### What you're trying to do is impossible.

---

With that said, if you have some way to ensure that the client code is trustworthy - perhaps the page and all of its scripts are loaded from a browser extension or local app, rather than from the server - this is pretty easy.

The simplest approach would be to use CORS. A script on B would make an authenticated cross-origin request (using XHR or Fetch) to A, requesting the data. The server at A would check that the user is authorized, and return the appropriate data, along with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: B` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` headers necessary for the script to see the response.

Slightly more complicatedly, you could do this using the [`Window.postMessage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). You'd create a listener for window messages in a script on B, and then open a window (iframe, popup, maybe even separate tab) to a page on A. The page on A would have (or retrieve) the secret, and then call `postMessage` to send it to B.

In both cases, the secret never actually hits the server at B - it's entirely client-side, and could be stored in local storage or whatever might be needed on B - but of course you have to trust that the code on B isn't going to just make a same-origin XHR or Fetch to send the secret down to the server (or something similarly unfortunate). As mentioned above, if you can't trust the server at B, you can't trust any code that runs on B's origin (unless, somehow, none of that code actually comes from the server and you can be sure of that).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware that I have to trust server B to not send malicious javascript content in the first place, but this question is written with the assumption that the server will not do so because it can be detected and the service will loose all trust and will get bankrupt if exposed.
This approach will not work most likely though. I do not have session tokens for server A on server B or website B, so there is no way to authorize it directly from website B. This is also the reason why I would take a detour to website A, the authorization information is only stored there..

Comment: If the session tokens are cookie-based (and don't use the SameSite flag), then they'll be sent automatically no matter where the request comes from. Neither the server for B nor the JS code running in origin B needs to have any access to the tokens. However, if A is using a system where cross-origin requests don't work, use the `postMessage` approach instead. It's much simpler and easier to verify than messing about with inventing your own cryptosystem.

Comment: Yeah, cross-origin requests would not work anyway. The data needed from Server A is also encrypted and would need to be decrypted on the client beforehand ...
The postMessage approach seems kinda nice as all of this is running on the client, but I am not sure how the window of A can verify whether B should have access to the requested data or not. 
Is it possible for B to send a proof of such permissions to the target window of A without the user seeing such a proof, intercepting, stealing and using it for something fraudulent? This feels like it would be quite involved ..

Comment: `postMessage` lets you specify the origin that the message will go to, but you do have to trust that the user logged into A and the user logged into B are the same person or at least trust each other (same as for CORS). Preventing "fraudulent" access to the data is a total lost cause; the user can always, guaranteed, see any requests, responses, or stored data that the browser (not the web app, the actual web browser process) can see. There's nowhere you could hide data, tokens, keys, or script that the user couldn't see and use.

Comment: Website A needs to prove that it is allowed to see the client key, otherwise any website could create an iframe, ask for the user key and just get it, and we do not just trust any service out there. Note: Website A will have to be able to communicate with any origin.

Comment: I think I have a solution, but it is a little involved and I don't know whether it works:
Website B could ask window A for a service-session-token (sst), send it back to server B and authenticate the sst from server B via an api call. The sst includes an identifier of the user session and a one-time-reload-id (otrid) from server B to prevent fraud. Afterwards website B could ask window A for the data as the sst has been authorized via the api-call and the sst is for the current state.
Access to the key is now as secure as access to the current tab. After each page reload the otrid changes.

Comment: Nevermind, I think there is a security hole in there as well.

Well, thank you very much for your time and insight into communication within a web-browser. I'm just a math student that will go into cryptography and I'm trying to get a grasp on web security and I'm also messing around with inventing my own cryptosystem, but it's kinda fun and I learned a lot from it up until now. 

I will mark your answer as accepted as "What you're trying to do is impossible" seems to be the case. Any way I think about it there is no way to prevent a MitM-Attack, but maybe I'll get an idea someday ;)